# GUI Extension, Publish from Publishing Queue in 2013 sp1

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I am trying to get the publish from [Publish Queue extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/publishfrompublishingqueue.aspx) working in Tridion 2013sp1.

It doesn’t show up - but also no errors.

I’m guessing the new carbon theme has different ids of elements, and it doesn’t find the old one.

Any idea of how to get the IDs of those elements?  I’ve tried snooping around in the /Popup/PublishQueue files in Chrome, but no luck.  Any ideas?

**Update:**

Now the item shows in the Context menu.  Found the element IDs by doing View Source in the Tridion PublishQueue popup.  Also, we can look in the PublishQueueContextMenu.js file and around line 36 use console.log to show the item in the menu.

But, the problem is selecting publish gives me this error:  Command "PqPublish" is not registered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not have to change any code for that extension to work on 2013 SP1. I just followed the instructions from `install.txt`.

I did notice that it doesn't mention to increase the @modification attribute, which you should do (so the browser cache of all clients will be updated). Other than that, I immediately got the "Publishing" sub-menu when right-clicking on an entry in the Publishing Queue.

Comment: It should be working fine for 2013 SP1, the one on SDL Tridion World, still has references to 2013 GA icons. on Google Code I have an update to the [Publishing.css](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/Publish%20from%20Publishing%20Queue/trunk/Extensions.PublishFromPublishingQueue/Themes/Carbon/Publishing.css) that fixes that. And yes should add the increase of the @modification attribute in the System.config for clarity.